# Derivation: How do I derivate this

Tags: functions, polynomials

How do I deveriate the following expression?

[image]

The problem I have is the n in d^n.

This expression is part of a bigger task of mine :

> Show via complete induktion that [image] is true for all n  from the natural numbers.  Fn is a polynomial of degree n.

How do i approach this problem?

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: `SeriesCoefficient[Exp[-x^2], {x, 0, n}]`

Comment: can you explain that to me? I dont really get it yet.

Comment: I think this is a bit unrelated to Mathematica, but here is a hint: It is (probably) not meant that you should find $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2}$ explicitly.

Comment: @mickep I know i have to proof that the function above also applies when i change n with n+1. But to do so i need to solve the equation with n+1 and i dont really know how because of the n in d^n. I only know the derivation with d/dx for example or as d f(x) / dx

Comment: Perhaps `FullSimplify[SeriesCoefficient[Exp[-y^2], {y, x, n}] n!, Element[n, Integers] && n > 0]` (from V. Reshetnikov) or `D[F[n][x] Exp[-x^2], x] // Factor` is a better hint.  But your question seems to be about mathematics, not the technical software *Mathematica*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you show that the (first) derivative of Exp[-x^2] yields a polynomial times Exp[-x^2].

```
D[Exp[-x^2], x]
```

-2 E^-x^2 x

which is (-2x) E^-x^2.  Then you show that the derivative of an arbitrary polynomial times Exp[-x^2] yields another polynomial times E[-x^2].  For arbitrary polynomial F[x] we find:

```
D[F[x] Exp[-x^2], x]
```

-2 E^-x^2 x F[x] + E^-x^2 Derivative[1][F][x]

```
Simplify[%]
```

E^-x^2 (-2 x F[x] + Derivative[1][F][x]).

This is E^-x^2 times a polynomial of one-higher order than F[x].

Q.E.D.